# Minimum number of rotation of tuples such that all first terms of the tuples are non zero

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $K_n$ be an $n$-tuple with elements as the first n non negative numbers. For example $K_5$ can be $(2,3,1,4,0)$.

Let a "shift" be a rotation in the tuple, i.e. after a "shift" the $K_5$ from before becomes $(0,2,3,1,4)$.

If we have $K_n$ for the first m primes, i.e. $K_2,K_3, ...$ m terms. What is the maximum number of shifts we would need to say for sure that at some point the first term of all the tuples was not $0$.

EDIT: When shifting, all tuples shift simultaneously

Comment: Does a shift mean rotating all the $K_n$ simultaneously? So if you had $(0,1),(2,1,0)$, then one shift would give $(1,0),(0,2,1)$, two shifts $(0,1),(1,0,2)$, three shifts $(1,0),(2,1,0)$.

Comment: yeah, ill make it clear in the question

Comment: OEIS: [A058989](https://oeis.org/A058989)